# Scaling features based on an attribute

Tags: qgis, python, scale-factor

I would like to scale polygon features by a specific factor I have calculated for each feature in a feature class.

I know of the Scale tool, however it only allows for manual entry of a scale factor and I have hundreds of features, so I would like to automate this as much as possible.

The end product will have all of my features resized so that they have the same area, but still have their own shapes and dimensions.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this, preferably via python?  I can also utilize qGIS if a better function exists.

Comment: Can you determine it as a buffer distance then use the buffer tool with a buffer field instead of a set distance?

Comment: This was the first approach I took, however defining a factor to use in a buffer is quite difficult since the shapes of the polygons are all unique.  Would this even be possible because each feature is unique in shape/size?

Comment: How close do you need them to be the same? You could do a multiple ring buffer with a list of distances stepped by say 0.1 and then pick the ones that match or are close enough to the intended area.

Comment: I need them to be pretty much as close as possible.  After your comment, I started thinking of an approach - I am going to make a buffer, say 1 foot of the features, then compare the area difference between the original and the buffer.  From there, I may be able to calculate a factor that can be used as a buffer for each feature.  Will post results once done.

Comment: Yeah, I am back to square one on the buffer distance.  It's proving to be quite difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: I ended up using the centroid of the polygons to do my process rather than the polygons themselves.  Using the centroids, it was obviously much easier to calculate a radius which generated a 1 acre polygon.  If anyone comes along and has an idea for using polygons, please share your knowledge! :)